# ASP.NET Navigate to section on page (help files)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am writing a help page with sections. What I want to do is allow navigation to a particular section (depending on what page the user clicked help from) rather than always landing at the top of the page.

My web app is written in ASP.NET; can anyone point me in the direction of how to set this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "bookmarks" for this... for example:

```
<a href="yourpage.aspx#Help">Help</a>
```

Will take you to the following "bookmark" on the yourpage.aspx page...

```
<a id="Help"></a>
```

Update! The `name` attribute should not be used for this, as per the [W3C HTML5 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete).

> Authors should not specify the name attribute on a elements. If the
>   attribute is present, its value must not be the empty string and must
>   neither be equal to the value of any of the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree other than the element's own ID, if any, nor be equal to the
>   value of any of the other name attributes on a elements in the
>   element's home subtree. If this attribute is present and the element
>   has an ID, then the attribute's value must be equal to the element's
>   ID. In earlier versions of the language, this attribute was intended
>   as a way to specify possible targets for fragment identifiers in URLs.
>   The id attribute should be used instead.

Comment: In HTML5, use id attribute instead of name since, html5 doesn't support name attribute on <a> tag. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad09f4da(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [<a name="xxx">](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp) tag.